# Handling the case where the user closes the browser or stops the process in the middle of the OAuth flow Google API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-api, google-oauth

I am integrating Google Drive API in my Django project.
My code is working perfectly but when I try to abort the authentication by either closing the browser without authenticating myself by logging into it or any sort of aborting results in freezing the whole app.

Here is the code,

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES,redirect_uri='show_courses')
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
with open(token_path, 'w') as token_file:
    token_file.write(creds.to_json())
```

everything get stuck on this line if user close the browser without authentication
`creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)`

Please let me know how to handle this situation. I am struggling for this from last few months.

Comment: You first need to find where it freezes by debugging your code.

Comment: @Siavoshkc It freeze at this line `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` Here it waits for the user to authenticate. when user close the window without authentication then too it keeps waiting for user to authenticate and results in freezing the whole app.

Comment: Well I guess it does not freeze. It is just waiting for a connection.

Comment: It freezes. Please reply if you really know about it

Comment: The only way in my mind is to put auth process in another thread an kill that thread after 2 minutes or one.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why your app freezes when you abort the authentication process is because the `flow.run_local_server()` method is blocking. This means that it will not return until the user has authenticated or the authentication process has been aborted.

When you abort the authentication process, the `flow.run_local_server()` method will raise a `HttpError` exception. This exception is not caught by your code, so it will propagate up the stack and cause the entire app to crash.

To fix this, you need to catch the `HttpError` exception and handle it gracefully. For example, you could log the error and then redirect the user to a different page.

Here is an updated version of your code that handles the `HttpError` exception:

```py
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES,redirect_uri='show_courses')
try:
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
except HttpError as e:
    logger.error('Error authenticating to Google Drive: %s', e)
    return redirect('home')

with open(token_path, 'w') as token_file:
    token_file.write(creds.to_json())
```

This updated version of your code will log the error and then redirect the user to the home page if the authentication process is aborted.

In addition to handling the `HttpError` exception, you should also consider using a non-blocking approach to authenticating users. This would allow you to continue processing other requests while the user is authenticating.

One way to achieve this is to use a background task to authenticate the user. For example, you could use the Django Celery library to create a task that authenticates the user and then saves the credentials to the database. Once the task is complete, you can then notify the user that they have been successfully authenticated.

Another way to achieve this is to use a JavaScript library to authenticate the user in the browser. For example, you could use the Google OAuth JavaScript library to authenticate the user and then redirect them back to your Django app with the credentials.

Comment: After implementing try catch in my code as your said, yet nothing worked.  when I tried to close the browser without continuing authentication process that is by providing credentials, it shows this on CMD

Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=175385754659-p0k2ecgh5soupkxxxxxxk6ka619vdl4r.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A59293%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&state=xxxxxdUt9O6QEYCHA&access_type=offline

and freeze everything.